# how to justify expected value of estimated error in LMS estimation?

Tags: statistics

If we have estimator and error like below,

- `Estimator`: $\hat{\Theta} = E[\Theta|X]$
- `Error`: $\tilde{\Theta} = \hat{\Theta}-\Theta$

I get $E[\hat{\Theta}] =E[\Theta]$ from `Estimator`.
But how can I derive $E[\tilde{\Theta}]=0$, from `Error` logically?

Comment: Is $X$ a random variable?

Comment: @Snoop Yes it is

Comment: I think that by using the law of total expectation, we get
$$E[\hat{\Theta}|X]=E[E[\Theta|X]|X]=E[\Theta|X]$$
$$E[\tilde{\Theta}]=E[E[\tilde{\Theta}|X]]=E[E[\hat{\Theta}|X]-E[\Theta|X]]=E[E[\Theta|X]-E[\Theta|X]]=0$$

Comment: @Snoop I don't get this part [[Θ̃|]]=[[Θ̂|]−[Θ|]]

Comment: Linearity of expectations

Comment: @Snoop  Ohh I forgot linearity can be applied even within dependent random variables, Thx!